# On a pond: The usage of the indefinite article

Tags: indefinite-article

> Look! They are sailing boats on a pond.

Is the indefinite article possible in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but it is quite strange. The main reason for that is that in the context an indefinite article means you are surprised it is possible to sail boats on a pond. As opposed to just pointing out that someone is sailing on the pond you're pointing to.

Since the context shows you see the pond being mentioned you would expect a definite article. "Look! They are sailing boats on the pond."

A more focused example might be:

"Look! There's a kangaroo on the road!" Here you're pointing out that there is a kangaroo on the road. You're not surprised by the fact that a kangaroo could be on a road, but you feel it noteworthy there is one on the specific road you're looking at, maybe you need to swerve not to hit it.

"Look! There's a kangaroo on a bike!" Here you're surprised by the fact that a kangaroo can actually be on a bike. It's not that he's on the one in front of you the specific bike is an afterthought, the surprising fact is a kangaroo can ride a bike at all.